# how to change the login message

Tags: login

I have a late 2009 iMac 27" running 10.12.3

This is a computer that was in my office, connected to a network.  I had off-site support.  Now as I am preparing to give this to a friend, there is a partial login screen message.  The full message, visible with 10.7.x was how to contact support.  Now it is just an annoying leftover.  I would appreciate any assistance in getting rid of the message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with iMac, but usually there are two messages, the pre-login and the post-login message. They are stored in `/etc/issue` and `/etc/motd` file respectively. Simply edit those files (as root).